# MathML ApplyFunction Entity - where does it come from?

Tags: mathml, maple

I'm using `System.Xml.Linq` to parse MathML 2.0 via its associated DTD. Everything is fine except that Maple produces the `&ApplyFunction;` element which does not appear to be a DTD. Where is this element defined? I tried googling, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

⁡ is an entity that's treated as an operator (i.e., an mo element) in MathML. Its a valid Unicode character, with codepoint x2061: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2061/index.htm

ApplyFunction is normally used in order to prevent ambiguity, rather than as a required operator. For example, this code block

```
<mi>sin</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo>
```

is just as valid as this code block

```
<mi>sin</mi><mo>&ApplyFunction;</mo><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo>
```

and really there's no ambiguity in either case, but for some functions there may be.

⁡ should appear as an entity declaration in any MathML DTD.

Comment: It appears as an entity declaration, but not in the main file - there is a reference to some `.ent` file, but XLinq seems to ignore it completely.